# how to remove microsoft-network folder

Tags: uninstall, directory, delete

hey everyone i wanna delete this folder called microsoft-network how to do this

[CLick here for image to see what folder i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wHc2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a folder, it's a network resource. You can use it to connect to other computers (like accessing a folder on a different desktop pc / laptop or on a usb stick plugged into your router). That's why you can't delete it.